# Node.js - Access key from object

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

I try to access a key from an object I get back from an API but when I do so, I get the key of the object in a strange format.

This is what I get when I console.log the object (booking):

```
{ createdDate: 2018-03-26T11:36:09.694Z,
  date: 2018-03-26T13:45:00.000Z,
  ...,
  vouchers: 
   List [
    { value: 100,
      code: 'vouchercode',
      ...
    } 
   ]
}
```

When I then try to console.log the "vouchers" key:

```
booking.vouchers
```

I get this:

```
{ [Function: f]
  _receiver: { 
    createdDate: 2018-03-26T11:36:09.694Z,
    date: 2018-03-26T13:45:00.000Z,
    ...,
    vouchers: List [ [Object] ] },
  _scope: 
    { where: { bookingId: 5ab8db29b24991b50704445a },
    collect: 'voucher',
    include: 'voucher' },
  _targetClass: 'Voucher',
  find: [Function],
  getAsync: [Function],
  ...,
}
```

Why do I get it in this format and how do I convert it to a normal object like this?:

```
vouchers: [
 { value: 100,
   code: 'vouchercode',
   ...
 } 
]
```

I hope the problem is understandable and some of you can help :)

**Edit:**

This is my code:

```
Booking.findById id, {include:[ 'vouchers']}, (err, booking)->
  console.log booking
  vouchers = booking.vouchers
  console.log vouchers
```

*Note: I know this is coffeescript but I don't think thats the problem

Comment: what is the link of your API ? and when you console log the object what do you get ?

Comment: `and when you console log the object what do you get ?` --> It's explicitely in the question.

Comment: What does `console.log(booking.vouchers[0].value` show?

Comment: `console.log(booking.vouchers[0].value);`  `TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined`

Comment: Does the vouchers object have a view() function? Try `console.log(vouchers.view())`

Comment: Not a view function but there is a find() function. When I use that I get `Promise {<br>
  _bitField: 33554432,
  _fulfillmentHandler0: undefined,
  _rejectionHandler0: 
   [ {value: 100,
       code: 'vouchercode',
       ... ],
  _promise0: undefined,
  _receiver0: undefined }`

Comment: I think that object `booking` override method `toString` and therefore has "normal" output. Children  of `booking`, e.g. `booking.voucher`, don't have it and use default `toString`-method.

Comment: @NikolajNyboe Looks like you somehow downloaded the model of the data from the API instead of the actual data you were looking for, or you created a vouchers model and stored it in your db instead of the vouchers data.